# Playing Local audio files with expo-av - React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to develop a simple audio player in react-native using expo and for that i am using [expo-av](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/) api, which play/record audio file and for fetching audio files from phone, i am using [expo-media-library](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/).

The problem is **expo-media-library** provides an array of objects for each file with some properties, including **file path named 'uri'**. When i try to set that path with expo-audio source path, it does not work. i guess i need to establish a url link of the path but don't know how to do this.

**Project Sample**: https://snack.expo.io/@m_usman/audioplayer

Comment: Do you have any update on this?

Comment: Also interested in this. Can only get expo to play audio using static require calls but not with a uri.